# How to customize burndown chart on azuredevops

Tags: .net, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to add an efficient burndown chart to my azuredevop project dashboard.
I've been looking for a while on how to customize the **Burndown widget** in order to have the following display (plot is in day, start date is the current iteration start date, end date is the current iteration end date), and so let it switch automatically to the next iteration when it is necessary, but I don't find anything that allows me to do it.

Is there a way to do what I need to do automaticaly ?

To achieve on the following display, I used the bad one configuration (because it make me to update range interval at the end of each iteration, and also the filter criteria) :

[image: Display of burndown that I need]

And below is the configuration I used to  :

[image: configuration part 1]
[image: configuration part 2]

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

> Let it switch automatically to the next iteration when it is
>   necessary.

I'm afraid this could not be achieve now. Because initially, the design logic of dashboard is let you and your teams share information, monitor the WITs progress and trends **flexibility** with one **highly-configurable** dashboards.

Ever has the same puzzle and demand with you, after discuss more with the engineer from our Boards team, I clearly got the reason for this design.

As normal, dashboards is used for yourself or team leader to monitor the develop process. If we simply set the time period updated with the sprint automatically to display the data,  this is not very helpful for tracking the staged data. Because if the overall data looks very perfect, it will let the user easily ignore **potential** problems that exist within a certain period of time. Providing highly-configurable widgets in the dashboard, can very convenient for members to better track their development progress with the phased custom time period data analysis. Also, This is more conducive to the leader to find problems in time.

For this, you can refer to this doc: [About dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops).

> Gain visibility into your team's progress by adding one or more
>   widgets or charts to your dashboard. Customizable, highly-configurable
>   dashboards provide you and your teams with the flexibility to share
>   information, monitor progress and trends, and improve your workflow
>   processes. Each team can tailor their dashboards to share information
>   and monitor their progress.

---

Though this demand could not be achieve in dashboards, but our PMs has considered the convenience of this demands in many cases and taken it into Azure Devops. In the **Analytics** tab of **Sprints** pannel, you can view the Burndown chart within one iteration.

[image]

[Get insights into your team’s health with three new Azure Boards reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-155-update#get-insights-into-your-teams-health-with-three-new-azure-boards-reports)

---

There has one feature request raised on our official uservoice community: [Burndown Widget: Allow @CurrentIteration to be used](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/662066/burndown-widget-allow.html). If this feature could be expanded into widget, it can give you what you want.

To driving this new feature developed, you can vote and comment it there. The corresponding Product Team will review these tickets regularly, then task a consider about expand it into our roadmap.

Comment: Liang so it means that I should update the date range interval and criteria filter at each end of the sprint ? Is it possible to put the Burndown Trend to the dashboard ?

Comment: @GuillaumeP. Of course it has, use **Sprint Burndown** widget: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#sprint-burndown . This widget can always displays data for the current sprint. But its disadvantage is does not provide the configuration for users.

Comment: @Merling Liang  The "Sprint burndown" is is not as precise as the previous one. So it does not fit my need. Maybe I missed something ? Actually, my need is to present on the dashboard to my manager  the overview of the current iteration (are we in phase with what we need to deliver in time ? are we in late ? what is the globale trend ?)
If I have to switch it manually, when the sprint is over, it does not have any interest. Important data to show up is the actual one, and to see the progression. What is your opinion about this ? What is your preconisations ?

Comment: @GuillaumeP. Yeah, this is why I did not recommend and express it in my answer. Because of less maintain by our relevant team, it could not provide the same feature with the one in Sprint panel. In some cases, deliver the process shown in widget in time is a necessary step for leader. Because this can let leader monitor the sprint timely. This could be viewed in Sprint panel. For my team PM, the burndown widget was customized to display this week or month's develop process. Because our team have a phased goal need to tracking.

Comment: @GuillaumeP. Though the design would need more action to achieve what you want. But in another cases, the highly-configurable feature could let the tracing and data analyzed more flexible. Also, after discuss with my colleague, he said that there has one colleague raised the same [feature uservoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/662066/burndown-widget-allow.html). You can vote and comment it there. This can help for dring the new feature expanded by Boards team. Updated into my answer. Thus others SO users who have same demand can also vote it.